# opposite result happening from a procedural function

Tags: php

I have created a script using procedural php it uses 2 functions

**function 1#** is signup sending information to the database.

**function 2#** is a validate required fields.

I call these in the form and it works but only in reverse effect and I cannot figure out why, if the fields are empty it allows you to submit and send a blank query and if the fields have values it returns fields are required.

my validate function

```
function validate($name, $email, $password): array
{
    $errors = [];

    if ($name) {
        $errors[] = "Name is required";
    }
    if ($email) {
        $errors[] = "Email is required";
    }
    if ($password) {
        $errors[] = "Please enter a valid password";
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

The Form Page

```
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $errors = validate($name, $email, $password);

        if (empty($errors)) {
            signup($email, $name, $password);
        }
    }
```

and then the code to display the error

## My Form

```
<?php if (!empty($errors)) : ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($errors as $error) : ?>
            <li><?= $error ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>

<form name="form-registration" method="post">

    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" value="">
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" value="">
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
    <div>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password"name="password">
    </div>
    </fieldset>

    <input type="submit" value="insert">
</form>
```

Comment: The conditions in your validate function are backwards. `if ($name)` (and the same for the rest) is checking if the value of `$name` is "truthy" (not empty), in which case you write an error.

Comment: Yes, you should user $name = $_POST['name'] ?: ''; and  if ($name !='') same of rest of all fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
if($name){
   ///
}
```

this means when `name` value exists or is not empty so you need to reverse it like this

```
 if (!$name) {
        $errors[] = "Name is required";
    }
```

After editing the `validate` method it sould be like this

```php
function validate($name, $email, $password): array
{
    $errors = [];

    if (!$name) {
        $errors[] = "Name is required";
    }
    if (!$email) {
        $errors[] = "Email is required";
    }
    if (!$password) {
        $errors[] = "Please enter a valid password";
    }

    return $errors;
}
```